# PHP - $_GET method URL information pass?

Tags: php, session, get

I want to pass information from a page PHP to another PHP page, is it possible without using `$_GET` or with `$_SESSION`?

Comment: POST data? And what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can using `$_COOKIES[]`, and `setcookie()`:

Remember! Cookies expire.

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "My Cookie Value", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Then use:

```
echo $_COOKIES["cookie_name"];
```

Also, this may not be a very great choice, as the user may disable cookies in there browser, Therefore I do suggest you use `$_SESSION[]` and or `$_GET[]`. But if cannot use these super global variables, Then I suggest you use another way to store the data, Such as database.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Comment: i have used $_SESSION is that more secure than $_GET ?

Comment: @yassinegharsallah Yes, it is more secure than `$_GET`, `$_GET` is in the url and can be changed, `$_SESSION` cannot be changed, it can only be deleted from the user's side!